# Creating .cpp files from headers with inline methods and classes

Tags: c++

I have made a bunch of headers that directly implement methods and classes. I know that this is not the best pattern, I did it mainly because I was lazy and used Java before. The project that im working on is getting bigger, so the compile times explode because every recompile in the main.cpp has to recompile all the classes. This is because there arent any .o files for the classes and functions so the `#include` preprocessor creates a huge file with all the stuff in it.

Is there a way to **automatically** split all these headers into .cpp and .h files and move the implementations of all functions and classes into the .cpp ?

**My solution:**

I created a program in java to "parse" the code with regex to find function declarations and saved the function bodies for use in the `.cpp` file. then I replaced the bodies with an `;` and copied the function declarations in a `StringBuilder` and appended the body. To find the class names for `ClassName::` declarations I used regex too.

My regex:

Function declarations:
`(?m)(?!.*[\"}])(^.*\\S+ ([a-zA-Z0-9_+\\-=\\/*^\\[\\]]+)\\s*\\(.*\\)\\s*(const)?\\s*)\\{`

human-readable: "Lines that dont start with `}` or `"`, but with a random type name `\\S+` followed by a space, then the function name `[a-zA-Z0-9_+\\-=\\/*^\\[\\]]+`, an undefined parameter list `(.*)`, a optional `const` and finally a `{`.

Luckily this is the way i formatted my code :D

Comment: Automatically or by hand?  You could develop a blank stencil source file then copy and fill it in for each class.

Comment: _"Is there a way to split all these headers into .cpp and .h files and move the implementations of all functions and classes into the .cpp ?"_ Sure.. simply do so with your keyboard and mouse. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you thinking of module? Each .cpp file has a .h with the same name. The header contains and lists all the functions and variable names. The .cpp file includes the header and you write the functions there.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that id like to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also hate tedious pointless manual work.  What I do is use [cogapp](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/), which is a language-agnostic code generator.  It rocks.  I created a header file declaration generator for it,  [cog_addheaders.py](https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/blob/e72fc8061fb0d786e0da7a1d1e13ed5f15079a78/cog-batteries/cog_addheaders.py).  Then, I simply write the .cpp file, an initial, basically empty, .h file, and cogapp, plus my cogapp generator handles the rest :-)

For `static` and `virtual`, I add macros for `STATIC` and `VIRTUAL`, which expand to nothing in the .cpp, and `static` and `virtual` in the .h file.  I've been using it for a while, and it's super easy, I'm very comfortable with it :-)

Here's some examples:

- [WeightRandomizer.cpp](https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/blob/7f645390fb7d8e1005a46239c1f9a05d35d4b0bb/test/WeightRandomizer.cpp) and [WeightRandomizer.h](https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/blob/7f645390fb7d8e1005a46239c1f9a05d35d4b0bb/test/WeightRandomizer.h)

  - the generator is in the .h file, in the section `[[[cog]]]` up to the next `]]]`
  - the generated code is everything from there up to the next `[[[end]]]`
- [WeightsPersister.cpp](https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/blob/7f645390fb7d8e1005a46239c1f9a05d35d4b0bb/src/WeightsPersister.cpp) vs [WeightsPersister.h](https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/blob/7f645390fb7d8e1005a46239c1f9a05d35d4b0bb/src/WeightsPersister.h)
- templated example: [NetLearner.h](https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/blob/7f645390fb7d8e1005a46239c1f9a05d35d4b0bb/src/NetLearner.h) and [NetLearner.cpp](https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/blob/7f645390fb7d8e1005a46239c1f9a05d35d4b0bb/src/NetLearner.cpp)

Comment: thanks, this is a nice tool to create headers automatically. unfortunately my problem is, that i have the fully implemented headers and need to create cpp files.

Comment: Sure, so you will need to copy the contents from the header file to the .cpp once, then add 'MyClassName::' in front of each method name, then erase all the methods from the header, and replace them with the `cog` block.  This is quite quick to do, since I have done it many times before.  I use gedit as my editor, nothing fancy :-)

Comment: (If you want to try this easily, without committing your project to it, just to see how it works, you can clone one of my smaller projects, eg https://github.com/hughperkins/Jinja2CppLight , and build it, and try adding new methods for `Template` class, in the .cpp file, and see what happens in the .h file, when you build. Make sure that `python` is in the `PATH` when you run cmake)

Comment: as i noticed that i have 51 files to change i used an alternative solution. see above ;)

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there a way to split all these headers into `.cpp` and `.h` files and move the implementations of all functions and classes into the `.cpp` ?"*

You can of course move these inline function definions to separate `.cpp` files from the header files.

Suppose you have something like

```
class A {
public:
    int foo();

private:
    int x;
};
```

in the header, and

```
inline int A::foo() {
    return x;
}
```

in the `.cpp`, the compiler will anyway decide to optimize such code being inlined or not (think of the `inline` keyword merely as being a hint).

Unless you have class template declarations/definitions you should almost always move your definition code to separate compilation units, instead of having it in the headers (and so needing to recompile any dependent translation units using that header file upon changes in your definition).

Comment: I would not bother mentioning the inline keyword at all. I would not even do that in my own code except for rare cases.